# jquery - beforeshow and beforeshowday on an inline datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code which works fine on a datepicker attached to an input but does not run the beforeshow and beforeshowday parts when used with an inline datepicker.

What can I do to get around this??

```
$('.mydate').datepicker({
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: 'yy, m, d',
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+2Y',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            selectdatesElem = $(input).siblings("div").find("select.startdates");
            $(input).siblings("div").find("select.startdates").find("option").each( function() {
                  startDates.push($(this).val())
            });
            $(input).siblings("div").find("select.availdates").find("option").each( function() {
                  eventDates.push($(this).val())
            });
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            for (var i = 0; i < eventDates.length; i++) {
                  if (date.getFullYear()+", "+date.getMonth()+", "+date.getDate() == eventDates[i]) {
                        return [false, 'eventDay'];
                  } 
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < startDates.length; i++) {
                  if (date.getFullYear()+", "+date.getMonth()+", "+date.getDate() == startDates[i]) {
                        return [true, 'eventDay'];
                  }
            }
            return [false, ''];
        }, 
        onSelect: function(dateText, input, inst) {
            var selectedDateParts = dateText.split(',');
            selectdatesElem.val(parseInt(selectedDateParts[0]) + ", " + (parseInt(selectedDateParts[1])-1) + ", " + parseInt(selectedDateParts[2])).change();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean by an "inline datepicker"?

Comment: `<div class='mydate'></div>`

Comment: an array which is populated baed on the options in a select menu

Comment: Well it generates an error so you need to post where that comes from, where `startDates` comes from. In other words, a complete code example. And preferable a working jsFiddle. Oh, and what do you want beforeShow and beforeShowDay to actually do?

Answer (score 0):

I put this through JSLint and it came back with some missing semicolons and `var i` was already declared (remove var from second for loop). The lines missing semicolons:

```
startDates.push($(this).val())
eventDates.push($(this).val())
```

It also came back with this line missing a radix parameter. The radix is for which base the value is in (decimal, binary, hexadecimal, etc). If you just want decimal add ,10 to the end of the val() and parseInt() functions, like so

```
selectdatesElem.val(parseInt(selectedDateParts[0], 10) + ", " + (parseInt(selectedDateParts[1], 10) - 1) + ", " + parseInt(selectedDateParts[2],10 ),10).change();
```

I doubt these changes will fix it, but it is worth a shot.

I looked into it a bit more and it will run with beforeShow, but when I add beforeShowDay it doesn't display.

I looked at the code for a while and the api docs and it sounded like there needed to be an input field along with the datepicker. I see that you are reading from select elements, but I think that the beforeShow is missing the input element that it needs.